# Firebase: pegar utilizador pelo seu email em Javascript FIrebase v9 (modular)

Tags: javascript, firebase, get, firebase-database

Olá,

na minha plataforma implementei o sistema de login com a autenticação do firebase.
Como posso pegar um utilizador do firebase, segundo o seu email?

Este código retorna as informações do utilizar loggado no momento. Eu quero o retorno de um utilizador segundo um email que eu recebo de um input.

```
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
const user = auth.currentUser;
if (user !== null) {
  // The user object has basic properties such as display name, email, etc.
  const displayName = user.displayName;
  const email = user.email;
  const photoURL = user.photoURL;
  const emailVerified = user.emailVerified;

  // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use
  // this value to authenticate with your backend server, if
  // you have one. Use User.getToken() instead.
  const uid = user.uid;
}
```

Estou a utilizar Firebase/JS - Versão 9 para a Web (modular).

Não sei se faz diferença, mas a estrutura da base de dados em tempo real, segue abaixo.

[image: Esquema da Base de Dados em Tempo Real]

Comment: Se você quer logar por e-mail/senha pode usar o método signInWithEmailAndPassword. Para retornar os dados somente com e-mail pode pesquisar por getUserByEmail https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users?hl=pt-br

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a função `equalTo` para isso:

```js
import { getDatabase, ref, query, get, orderByChild, equalTo } from "firebase/database";

const emailInput = "super.admin@trilhos.p"; // exemplo de email

const dbRef = ref(getDatabase());
get(query(dbRef, `users`), orderByChild(`email`), equalTo(emailInput)).then((snapshot) => {
  if (snapshot.exists()) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
  } else {
    console.log("No data available");
  }
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
```